# Página estranha depois de adicionar Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Após adicionar as dependências do Primefaces o projeto ignora minha página `/home.xhtml` que está no xml e mostra uma url `/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo`
toda a vez que eu executo o projeto.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Qual XML você quer dizer quando diz "que está no xml"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver o problema apenas sobrescrevendo o método configure da classe WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter do spring-security e o deixando assim:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll() //Essa é alinha que faltava
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
            .permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Verifique seu web.xml, no meu estou definindo como pagina inicial o index.xhml:

```html
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```